# Import shared module from folders

Tags: python, module, import

I have modules written in c++ for python. For example, here is folders structure:

```
|Main/
|--SubMain/
|----Module1.so
|--SubMain2/
|----Module2.so
|----Module3.so
```

Now I want to import this into python like:

```
import Main.SubMain.Module1
```

First of all, I did recursively for all that folders:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(...)
```

And now I can do:

```
import Module1
import Module2
import Module3
```

But I want to specify the exact folder of the module. I tried to put `__init__.py` into all folders but this didn't help me. This way modules aren't visible for python. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make something a package, you need to add `__init__.py` (not `__input__.py`) to the folders. So if you add `__init__.py` to Main, Submain1, and Submain2, then call sys.path.append with the parent of Main, you should be able to import as you desire.

Comment: Sorry, I used `__init__.py`, not input. I added that files but didn't call `sys.path.append`. Thanks.